# Are my expectations for undergraduate student support unrealistic?

Tags: teaching, united-kingdom, learning

I'm attending a Russel group university in the UK, and studying Computer Science in the 2nd year of an undergraduate degree.

I'm reasonably happy with the vast majority of the taught content, but sometimes certain parts of the syllabi trip me up or I'm not sure if I'm correctly understanding how to approach solving certain problems. At Sixth Form, if I was stuck I'd try and work it out myself and then ask the subject tutor if I wasn't getting anywhere.

At university, there appears to be a stark difference in the academic support offered. Many lecturers do not have regular office hours and are unresponsive when asked if an appointment could be scheduled. Questions sent via email aren't comprehensively addressed, even when it's clear that substantial independent work using external resources (content from other universities, various textbooks etc) has been done to try and tackle the problem (vs. simply asking for an answer with no work to show for it). There's little I can do other than consult my peers when I don't understand something - and if many of us are stuck we feel completely lost.

There also seems to be a difference in the support materials provided. Many modules don't publish example problems or solutions, provide any form of solutions to past exam questions or sign-post relevant textbook exercises. This differs greatly to previous exams prior to university, where the exam board would make marking schemes, model solutions and examiner reports available each year. I feel ill-prepared for most exams, because I find it difficult to verify my answers to practice problems are correct.

Is this the norm for undergraduate study, or are these signs of issues within my department? Are my expectations in terms of academic support unrealistic?

Comment: I don't know about UK, but in my country some 30 years ago, and for many years afterwards, when I was a student, professors were not used to hold office hours and in most courses you were on your own if something wasn't clear. Now, in many universities, things are changing because of teaching evaluations which, among other things, assess also the responsiveness of professors. I can imagine, though, that a few old-style professors simply continue to ignore students. Does your university have a teaching evaluation system?

Comment: I don't know much about universities other than my own but I believe your expectations are indeed a little unrealistic. Generally speaking, in university you are expected to be able to study on your own. You should be able to solve problems with your theoretical knowledge of the subject. They are meant to test your understanding, so posting the solutions for previous exams is counterproductive. Regarding academic support: I understand usually it's the job of teaching assistants and, frankly speaking, professors have more important stuff to do than worry about failing students.

Comment: @ПетяНарышкин: Yours is an intriguing perspective -- because my undergraduate experience was almost exactly the opposite. Granted, I attended a smaller liberal arts school with a (relatively) strong engineering program, and many classes didn't have a TA. But *every* professor was expected to hold office hours at least once a week where you could go get support. Yes, they almost always wanted to see that you had attempted the problems first; but if you got stuck, they were usually happy to explain what went wrong. And you were encouraged to seek out this help sooner rather than later.

Comment: Thanks for all your thoughts on this. @ПетяНарышкин You mentioned "Regarding academic support: I understand usually it's the job of teaching assistants" - there are no teaching assistants familiar with/assigned to at least one of the modules.

MassimoOrtolano Yes, there's an evaluation system. But there's very little transparency as to what is done with (and indeed the actual values) the results. Certainly it's unclear what changes have been made.

Comment: I'm in the U.S., but first blush is your experience may be close to standard. Point 1: A college professor's main job is research/publication, teaching is secondary (and time/attention will reflect that). Point 2: In traditional college classes it is unusual to hand out "practice/model tests", prior exams, programming solutions, etc. Admittedly it sounds like your lecturers are on the low end for office hours/support. A CS major in 2nd year should find the material fairly easy to work through (possibly with lots of time) or later work will be unapproachable.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, @DanielR.Collins. I'm not likely to fail by any means - I'm on track to get a first for the year. It's just little parts of e.g. a module's lecture slides that might not make sense (even after reading related literature) - often because because all other literature does X/describes X differently or a problem Y that you (think) can solve [and /can/ solve similar exercises from texbooks], but you can't reproduce what's shown in a lecture or the module notes.

Comment: Consider also asking your extra topical questions here on the SE Computer Science forum ("Q&A for students, researchers and practitioners of computer science").

Comment: I disagree with the votes to close. The question is basically, "what is a normal level of undergraduate academic support at a university?" It just happens to be posed from the point of view of an undergrad hoping to receive such support. Equivalently, it could have been posed like this: "What level of academic support should we normally provide to undergrads?"

Comment: Voting to reopen, as this can occur in grad school as well.  The basic phenomenon described by OP occurred as he progressed higher and deeper in his studies.

Comment: @BenCrowell The question is _Is this the norm for undergraduate study_, the close reason is _Questions about problems facing undergraduate students_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are my expectations in terms of academic support unrealistic?

Yes. You're describing the general existing level of academic support at your school, and that is by definition the normal level of academic support at your school.

This kind of thing varies greatly from one school to another, and most of the variation depends on the prestige of the school. Your school is in the Russell Group, which AFAICT (being American) means that it's a top-level research university with highly selective admissions. At that type of school, faculty are often highly focused on research rather than teaching, and the attitude is often that if an undergrad was smart enough to get in, they should be smart enough to succeed by going to lectures, reading the book, and doing the work independently.

Taking an example of such a school at the University of California system here in the US, the schedule of office hours published for [math](https://math.berkeley.edu/courses/office-hours) and [psychology](http://psychology.berkeley.edu/people/faculty-office-hours) suggests that different departments have different expectations for faculty office hours, and some faculty have no office hours at all, even though they are teaching lecture classes. Presumably there are TAs for a lot of these courses.

As you move down the ladder to less prestigious schools here in the US, you see more and more academic support being offered. Here in California, we have a three-tier system. The next tier below UC is the Cal State system. There, a typical teaching load might be 12 units, and someone teaching that many units is contractually required to have 4 hours of office hours every week.

After that, the next step down is the community college system. At the California community college where I teach, I'm required to do 5.5 hours of office hours every week. We also have extensive support services. We have a math lab, writing tutors, and students paid to work as tutors in the sciences.

> There also seems to be a difference in the support materials provided. Many modules don't publish example problems or solutions, provide any form of solutions to past exam questions or sign-post relevant textbook exercises.

This type of support is the sort of thing that is typically considered normal at the lower rungs of the ladder, but not at the higher rungs. At the type of school you're attending, the expectation in a certain course might be, for example, that you decide for yourself what problems to do out of the book, rather than being given a list. If you need to see solutions for exercises, you can, for example, find a textbook on the subject that has solutions for some problems.

Comment: Both of your links are of the math department.

Comment: I added the link that I believe was meant for the psychology department.

Comment: Prestigious universities often take the GIGO* approach to undergraduate teaching: you can only do so much damage in 4 years. *Good stuff In, Good stuff Out.

Comment: +1 for *"This type of support is the sort of thing that is typically considered normal at the lower rungs of the ladder, but not at the higher rungs."* I've just finished my undergrad at a non-Russell Group, poorly ranked UK uni and help was always available if I wanted (every lecturer had an open-door policy, exam solutions always provided, PhD students running a weekly help desk etc etc). It's only from speaking to friends at top unis that I've come to realise this level of support is unusual.

Comment: "If you need to see solutions for exercises, you can, for example, find a textbook on the subject that has solutions for some problems." - I slightly disagree with this reasoning. The primary purpose of having questions and solutions from previous exams available is to familiarize oneself with the individual style of questions and expectations of the particular class and its professor. No textbook can provide that.